# specific period fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Hi
I need to use a specific period, eg 08:00 to 12:00, 14:00 to 18:00.

Comment: Only have that section displayed?  Only have that section be where events can be added?  What are you looking to do?  Adding new views to fullcalendar can be done via extension of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

not completely sure what you are asking, but seems like `minTime` and `maxTime` might be what you are looking for:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/maxTime/